# Graphql schema causing error on project-config/apply

Tags: graphql, projectconfig

Craft v3.5.7

First off, **graphql is not being used on this site** so I'm not sure why the schemas are being generated and causing errors. The graphql.yml file contents:

```
publicToken:
  enabled: false
  expiryDate: null
```

There are graphql schemas that get generated (I assume during a `project-config/apply`?) and during a deploy, the `project-config/apply` is failing due to an error:

```
Applying changes from your project config files ... error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Public Schema' for key 'gqlschemas_name_unq_idx'
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO `gqlschemas` (`uid`, `name`, `isPublic`, `scope`, `dateCreated`, `dateUpdated`) VALUES ('c8b6ee58-XXXXXX', 'Public Schema', 1, '[]', '2021-10-06 17:28:52', '2021-10-06 17:28:52')
```

I was able to delete the schema file locally and delete that record from the db and get project-config to apply w/o errors but after committing/merging to staging, the schema files are regenerated and it still throws this error (even after deleting the record from the db manually).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

GraphQL is enabled by default in Craft CMS. Have you tried adding
`'enableGql' => false`
to your `general.php` config file? This should disable anything related to GQL, including the schemas. Then go to the Utilities -> Project Config and rebuild your config.

Ref: https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#enablegql